# Kendo how to apply auto width to foreign key Dropdown in MVC grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hello I have a kendo foreign key dropdown but when I open the dropdown in edit mode then width should be auto. Now text is wrapping to next line instead of single line.

```
columns.ForeignKey(c => c.CountryId, (SelectList)ViewBag.AllCountries).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "double" }).Title("Country");
```

Issue

[image: dropdown needs auto width]

Answer (score 0):

Kendo Dropdown has an autoWidth option that will set the width of the dropdown list according to the widest item in the list. You can set that option in the grid's Edit event.

Configure your grid's Edit event handler:

.Events(events => events.Edit("onGridEdit"))

Then in "onGridEdit":

```
    function onGridEdit(e) {
       let ddl = e.container.find("[data-role='dropdownlist']").data("kendoDropDownList");
       if (ddl) {
          ddl.setOptions({
             autoWidth: true
        });
    }
}
```